# SharePoint 2013 teamsite don't want /SitePages/Home.aspx for home page

Tags: 2013, team-sites, welcome-page

We have some sites that are based on the publishing template and we are able to use the welcome page item to have clean urls like:

https://farm/managedpath/publishingsite

And a page in the page library like default.aspx is the page at that url, but it doesn't add the /Pages/default.aspx to the url.

We have one site that is a teamsite and we have set a homepage following [this tutorial](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/09/05/how-to-set-a-page-as-home-page-in-sharepoint-2013-site/) But unfortunately when the user types in

https://farm/managedpath/teamsite

It changes to

https://farm/managedpath/teamsite/SiteAssets/NewHomepage.aspx

Is there a way to get the teamsite to not change the url? Just have site collection admin permissions, so nothing in central admin.